# How to debug a trigger in Oracle SQL developer (version 20.4.1.407)?

Tags: oracle, debugging, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following before-insert trigger, that assigns a sequence number to a record of an intersection table:

```
before insert on psln
for each row 
declare v_seqnr number;
begin
  select nvl(max(psln_seqnr),0) into v_seqnr from psln where pers_id = :new.pers_id;
  :new.psln_seqnr := v_seqnr + 1;
end;
```

Now i want to debug this trigger to see if v_seqnr gets the proper value, depending on the value of :new.pers_id. These are the steps i take:

- i configure the Start Debugging Option (Tools - Preferences - Debugger) as follows:

[image: Preferences - Debugger]

(when i choose a different option, my stack window remains empty while debugging, see below)

- i compile the trigger for debugging (Ctrl-Shift-F8)
- i place a breakpoint on the begin-statement
- i start debugging the trigger (Ctrl-Shift-F10) and get the following debug popup window, where i enter the values 1,1 for the insert-statement, that will cause the trigger to fire:

[image: debug popup window]

- i press OK and see the following (note the green V on the red breakpoint, which i think is the point of execution):

[image: debugging 1]

- when i now click on the Step-Into debug-icon with the red arrow (or press F7), i expect to jump to the first line of code in the begin-block, but nothing happens ...
- i also expect to see the value 1, when holding my mouse over the :new.pers_id expression, but this also does not work

Can someone please explain me what i am doing wrong or what i have forgotten?

Comment: Nothing I don't think..I've noticed in recent versions the step into starts you in the object being debugged, not the anon block. You are actually debugging your trigger...what are you wanting to do in the anon block?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The object being debugged is the psln_insert trigger. I suppose that with "the anon block" you mean the code that we see in the PL/SQL Debug window (3rd snapshot). This window pops up when pressing the debug-icon from inside the trigger. No indeed, i am not interested in debugging the code in that anon block, but i assume that block is there to force the trigger to fire.
My breakpoint is in the trigger code (that i also have compiled for debugging), but i cannot step through the code, although it looks like the execution halts at that breakpoint (see the last snapshot)

Comment: Oh, ok...I thought based on screenshot it was working. I'll take a look at a bit.

Comment: If it was working, i would not ask this question :-) Please see my second last and last steps (in the dotted list). I clearly say that "nothing happens" and that "this also does not work"

Comment: I really appreciate that you are taking the time and trouble to look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Not related to your debugging problems, but - if you're really using that trigger, consider not to. "MAX + 1" works in a single-user environment, but will fail sooner or later in a multi-user one when two (or more) users fetch the same MAX and produce the same "new seqnr". It might be *silent*, but it also might be *loud* if there's a unique/primary key on that column.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. There is indeed a unique index on the pers_id and psln_seqnr fields and i am aware of possible unique index violations. In this case there is a single-user environment, so there is no problem. But if it would be a multi-user environment, the chance that 2 users assign a new language to the same person in the same 5 milliseconds, is so incredibly small, that i would probably ignore that risk.

Comment: But to be completely sure, a temporary intersection table-lock would be an option. It is also possible to lock the specific person-record temporarily and only allow inserts on the intersection table for that person when there is no lock on the person-record.

Comment: back to the mechanics of debugging your trigger, i reproduced what you're seeing locally on my rig...and I THINK it's a bug. I can't explain what's happening...the local object 'trigger' for some reason isn't active during the debug session

Comment: Thanks so much for looking into it. A bug indeed seems to be the most reasonable explanation. I will speak with an ex-colleague tonight an share my screen. He is a very experienced Oracle developer, and hopefully he can disprove our assumption!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a known bug, in SQLDEVELOPER, one fix for it, could be instead of use an ANNONIMOUS PROCEDURE (which is created when you type in the "lady bug"), you can try to fire the trigger by a normal STORE PROCEDURE, that means, you can create a "dummy", procedure which emulates the insert, compile it for debug, an run it, if all work well, your execution should stops in the trigger's break point, is like to do a simulation of debug a procedure which has a trigger in.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try it out as soon as i have time for it.